# How to access keep accessing data from a scrapiad table with R?

Tags: r

I have the following R script with the result that you can see, that is an initial table. Each record in the purchase order column has additional data, they function as a hyperlink if it can be called that, now how can I access the data in each of the records in the purchase order column?

#Scprit R

```
urls.colombia.compra <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=", 
               0:11, 
               "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_=")

library(rvest)

base.colombia.compra <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table)

base.colombia.compra

base.colombia.compra
# A tibble: 578 x 6
   `Orden de Compra` `Entidad Estatal`             `Fecha de la ord~ Estado Instrumento   Total 
               <int> <chr>                         <chr>             <chr>  <chr>         <chr> 
 1             72683 UNIDAD ADMINISTRATIVA ESPECI~ 2021-07-16 20:05~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $453,~
 2             72670 SUPERINTENDENCIA DE ECONOMIA~ 2021-07-16 16:51~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $252,~
 3             72648 BOGOTA D.C - UNIDAD DE PLANE~ 2021-07-16 14:44~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $179,~
 4             72638 ESTABLECIMIENTO PENITENCIARI~ 2021-07-16 14:13~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $1,77~
 5             72631 INPEC - ESTABLECIMIENTO PENI~ 2021-07-16 12:56~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $1,67~
 6             72605 POLICIA NACIONAL - GESTION G~ 2021-07-15 20:01~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $2,97~
 7             72524 FOGAFIN                       2021-07-15 08:41~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $5,97~
 8             72502 INSTITUTO DE FOMENTO Y DESAR~ 2021-07-14 22:22~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $1,98~
 9             72471 ANTIOQUA - MUNICIPIO DE ITAG~ 2021-07-14 09:58~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $28,6~
10             72433 AGENCIA DE RENOVACION DEL TE~ 2021-07-13 16:21~ Emiti~ IAD Software~ $282,~
# ... with 568 more rows
```

Comment: Each number that is how I register in the "purchase order" column in the scrip result table has additional values. If I go directly to the web page and select one of the purchase order records, it opens another window with data, I would like to be able to extract that data also to make up another table.

Comment: > urls.colombia.compra <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra",
+                                "orden de compra"
+                                )
> 
> library(rvest)
> 
> base.colombia.compra <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table)
> 
> base.colombia.compra
# A tibble: 0 x 0

Comment: How can I bring all the records in the Instrument column without limiting it to just  "tool = IAD% 20Software% 20I% 20-% 20Microsoft"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct all the urls using  -

```
library(rvest)
all_urls <- paste0('https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/', base.colombia.compra$`Orden de Compra`)
```

and then use `purrr::map_df` as -

```
new_res <- purrr::map_df(head(all_urls), ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table())

# A tibble: 29 x 6
#      No Articulo                              Cantidad Unidad  Precio   Total   
#   <int> <chr>                                    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   
# 1     1 "wms01--AAA-10842EAEASENT Microsoft®…     7680 "Unida… 56.857,… 436.664…
# 2     2 "wms01--SY9-00004EAEASENT Microsoft®…      120 "Unida… 110.290… 13.234.…
# 3     3 "wms01--NK4-00002EAEASAP Microsoft®P…      120 "Unida… 29.070,… 3.488.4…
# 4     4 "wms01--IVA"                                 1 "Unida… 0,00     0,00    
# 5    NA ""                                          NA ""      Total    453.387…
# 6     1 "wms01--021-07161 Microsoft®Office S…       95 "Unida… 811.133… 77.057.…
# 7     2 "wms01--3YF-00124 Microsoft®OfficeMa…        4 "Unida… 811.133… 3.244.5…
# 8     3 "wms01--9EA-00232 Microsoft®WindowsS…        8 "Unida… 4.328.7… 34.630.…
# 9     4 "wms01--9EA-00233 Microsoft®WindowsS…       40 "Unida… 1.442.5… 57.702.…
#10     5 "wms01--R18-01634 Microsoft®Windows®…      147 "Unida… 161.143… 23.688.…
# … with 19 more rows
```

Note that I have used `head(all_urls)` to test the answer on small sample. Remove `head` when you want to extract all the data.

This also extracts additional rows with value 'Total' in `Precio` column. If you want to remove those use -

```
library(dplyr)

new_res <- new_res %>% filter(!is.na(No))
```

Comment: Do you know how I can include a column with the order number in the new table, to know which order number corresponds to each record?

Comment: You can use `new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, ~.x %>% read_html() %>% html_table() %>% .[[1]] %>% mutate(order_number = basename(.x), .before = 1))`